# rhc setup undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am trying to setup the OpenShift Client tool `rhc` on my Mac but I keep getting the following error:

```
An unexpected error occured: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

I have tried updating Ruby to the latest version from MacRuby and I have Git & Xcode installed.

I have manually installed the `net-ssh` gem as it was mentioned in another post but that made no difference. I also tried to install various alternative versions of `highline` (.11, .12, .14 & the latest = .21), but again, it made no difference.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: This should be posted as a bug report to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online instead of stack overflow.com, as it is a tooling issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: @developercorey You are correct, but they'll resolve the issue in matter of days, while the guys here have a solution that works hours after it occurred. Enjoy and share.

Comment: @ItayGrudev Yes, they have a good workaround, but this question was posted 4-5 times (duplicates) and there is not a real fix which is to run gem update rhc and get the newest fixed version, and the engineers would have been alerted to the issue more quickly via the bugzilla reports, vs questions on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rhc gem has been updated, please run `gem update rhc` and you will get the newest fixed version which is rhc-1.25.3

Comment: Thanks, all working now. When I first got the error, I searched and searched but couldn't find anything that helped me fix it. Being new to OpenShift and rhc, I wasn't sure if it was my mac or something else but the OpenShift website said I should come here to ask for help. Anyways, thanks for letting me know about the update.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall rhc
$ sudo gem uninstall httpclient
$ sudo gem install httpclient -v 2.3.4
$ sudo gem install rhc
$ rhc setup
```

Comment: How did you find out?

Comment: If I had time I would have traced the bug, but I wouldn't start downgrading things. Nicely done btw! Thanks!